# jboss throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Ljava/util/Collection;)

Tags: java, gradle, jboss, ear

Application is build successfully by gradle and genearate EAR file. But after deploying to JBOSS EAP 7.4, exception is throwing as below:

ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /demo/: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Ljava/util/Collection;)Z

Dependency:
implementation ('commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2')

Jboss:
C:\jboss-eap-7.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\commons\collections\main

[image]

module.xml:

```
    <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9">

    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="commons-collections-3.2.2.redhat-2.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="java.desktop"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Did you add the module dependency to your deployment?

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins! Thank you quick reply. No I haven't added module dependency the above is from jboss by default and properties value is private. Though I have added module dependency explicitly still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hit ctrl+shift+T and will see all the jar's who are all having this CollectionUtils class.

Below are the dependencies having same class but one of them have no isEmpty method in it.

```
implementation ('commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2')
com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.4.0
```

In my case only one place I am using this code, hence removing CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list) instead I am using list.isEmpty() and I am able to resolve this issue.
Big Thanks to my friend Manikantha who help me on this issue.